# Solve the integral equation $\int_0^{-x}f(t)dt= f(x) + x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

> Solve the integral equation $\displaystyle\int_0^{-x}f(t)dt= f(x) + x$.

Like it says, I'm playing around with even and odd functions and require a function such that $$\int_0^{-x}f(t)dt= f(x) + x\,.$$ I can't think how to go about it, any help appreciated.

If $F(x)=\int_0^{x}f(t)dt$, then $$F(-x)=F'(x)+x$$ with $F(0)=0$.  Then by differentiating both sides, we get
$$-F'(-x)=F''(x)+1.$$
How to solve this differential equation?

Comment: So overall you mean ${F(-x) = f(x) + x}$? where ${F(x)=\int f(x)dx}$? What have you tried?

Comment: The differential equation to be solved: $$\frac{d}{dx} \left(f(x) + x\right) = -f(x)$$

Comment: First I would use another dummy variable in the integral as $x$ is busy.  Second I would take a derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: have been trying of the form e^ax so that when the a comes down it can factor out to same function with a one. Was hoping for a solution that wasn't exponential but obviously I didn't specific that so it's not compulsory

Comment: @RossMillikan; why is $f$ differentiable?

Comment: The title is different, I answered to the title!

Comment: fair enough, pretty likely I made a mistake before admins changed it, removed the downvote,

Comment: Is that a problem found in a textbook or just a problem that you alone posed just for personal interest?

Comment: If found on textbook provide the whole problem statement

Comment: @Arnaldo:  because it always is in these problems.  More seriously, the left side is differentiable because of the fundamental theorem of calculus.  That means the right side is, too.

Comment: @RossMillikan In order for the left side to be differentiable for sure we must know if $f$ is continuous. Otherwise we have no clue!

Comment: The problem is that the OP does not give any further clues.

Comment: The left side is continuous.  Therefore the right side is continuous.  Therefore the left side is differentiable.  Therefore the right side is differentiable...

Comment: Indeed @GEdgar, my bad - silly mistake on my part :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From $$\displaystyle\int_0^{-x}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t=f(x)+x\,,\tag{#}$$ we see that $f$ is differentiable, and by taking the derivative of this integral equation with respect to $x$, we have $$-f(-x)=f'(x)+1\,.\tag{*}$$
That is, $f'$ is also differentiable, and by taking derivative of (*) with respect to $x$, we get
$$f'(-x)=f''(x)\,.$$
From (*), we get $f'(-x)=-f(x)-1$.  Therefore,
$$f''(x)=f'(-x)=-f(x)-1\,.$$
This means
$$f(x)=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)-1$$
for some constants $a$ and $b$.  Now,
$$x+a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)-1=f(x)+x=\int_0^{-x}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t=x-a\sin(x)-b\cos(x)+b\,.$$
This shows that $b=-1$ and $a=-b=1$.  That is,
$$f(x)=\cos(x)-\sin(x)-1\,.$$

---

Alternatively, we can continue from the results
$$F(-x)=F'(x)+x\text{ and }-F''(-x)=F'(x)+1\,,$$
by noting that
$$F(x)=F'(-x)+(-x)\text{ and }-F''(x)=F'(-x)+1\,.$$
Therefore,
$$F'(-x)=F(x)+x\text{ so }-F''(x)=\big(F(x)+x\big)+1\,.$$
Hence,
$$F''(x)+F(x)=-x-1\,.$$
This shows that
$$F(x)=A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)-x-1\,.$$
Because $F(0)=0$, we get $A=1$, so $$F(x)=\cos(x)+B\sin(x)-x-1\,.$$
That is,
$$F'(x)+x=-\sin(x)+B\cos(x)+x-1$$
and
$$F(-x)=\cos(x)-B\sin(x)+x-1\,.$$
This means $B=1$, and so $F(x)=\cos(x)+\sin(x)-x-1$, and we get
$$f(x)=F'(x)=F(-x)-x=\cos(x)-\sin(x)-1\,.$$

---

**P.S.**  Since there have been many questions regarding differentiability of $f$, I shall explain.  First, we at least need the assumption that $f$ is integrable.  Therefore, $\int_0^{-x}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t$ is a continuous function in $x$.  Then, (#) implies that $f$ is continuous.  Now, as $f$ is continuous, $\int_0^{-x}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t$ is a differentiable function in $x$, whence (#) tells us again that $f$ is differentiable.  By doing this cyclically infinitely (but countably) many times, we can conclude that $f$ is in fact a smooth function.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose  The integral equation already says that $f$ is continuous.  If $f$ is integrable, then $\int_0^{-x}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t$ is continuous in $x$.

Comment: @Rieman'sPointyNode Continuity of $f$ is a sufficient condition to say that the integral of it is differentiable. It's a theorem.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Yes, it does.  You now know that $f$ is continuous, and $f(x)=\int_0^{-x}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t-x$.  Since $f$ is continuous, $\int_0^{-x}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t$ is differentiable.

Comment: @Batominovski Not all integrabe functions are continuous.

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis The integral equation tells you that.  First, if $f$ is integrable, $\int_0^{-x}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t$ is continuous in $x$.  Therefore, $\int_0^{-x}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t-x$ is continuous in $x$.  Thus, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Batominovski Yes indeed the integral is continuous. But we do not know if it is differentiable. So we do not know if you can apply the common theorem about differentiation of integrals

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis ${f(x) = \int_{0}^{-x}f(x)dx - x}$. Since the integral is continuous (because it's implied the ${f(x)}$ is integrable) then that implies ${f(x)}$ is continuous (since it's the sum of two continuous functions) and so ${f}$ is continous and we can differentiate both sides

Comment: @Batominovski There are functions that are not continous but they are differentiable! But I hope in the OP's problem $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: you are correct, although the question I asked wasn't able to get me to the criteria I wanted to, I'm looking for a algebraic function that doesn't require if statements like absolute value, that has the property
y=1 if x>0
y=0 if x<0